# AppJar button linked to incorrect function

Tags: python, user-interface

To put it simply, a GUI button seems to be linked to the wrong function.
i have started to create a Vigenere cipher. A button that is meant to redirect to an encrypt function instead redirects to the decrypt function. W/ my current code it doesn't matter because the two codes are nearly the same but they will eventually have different uses and so need to be distinguished from each other.

i am unsure as to where the problem is so the whole code is attached.

```
    from appJar import gui
    app = gui("Vigenere Chipher")
    app.addLabel("title", "Vigenere Chipher")
    app.setBg("cyan")
    app.setSize(600,400)

    def press(Encrypt):
        app.removeAllWidgets()
        app.addLabel("title", "Encryption")
        app.addEntry("Phrase")
        app.setEntryDefault("Phrase", "Enter Phrase Here") 
        app.addEntry("Key")
        app.setEntryDefault("Key", "Enter Key Here")
        app.addLabel("RESULT", "This is your encrypted message: ")

        def press(Submit):
            phrase = app.getEntry("Phrase")
            key = app.getEntry("Key")        

        def press(Back):
            app.removeAllWidgets()
            app.addLabel("title", "Vigenere Chipher")
            app.setBg("cyan")
            app.setSize(600,400)

        app.addButtons(["Submit", "Back"], press)

    def press(Decrypt):
        app.removeAllWidgets()
        app.addLabel("title", "Decryption")
        app.addEntry("Phrase")
        app.setEntryDefault("Phrase", "Enter Phrase Here") 
        app.addEntry("Key")
        app.setEntryDefault("Key", "Enter Key Here")
        phrase = app.getEntry("Phrase")
        key = app.getEntry("Key")
        app.addLabel("RESULT", "This is your decrypted message: ")

        def press(Back):
            app.removeAllWidgets()
            app.addLabel("title", "Vigenere Chipher")
            app.setBg("cyan")
            app.setSize(600,420)
            app.addButtons(["Encrypt", "Decrypt", "Close"], press)

        app.addButtons(["Submit", "Back"], press)    



    app.addButtons(["Encrypt", "Decrypt", "Close"], press)



    app.go()
```

Thankyou for your help

Answer (score 0):

You've defined multiple functions with the same name `press`. Only the last definition will be used (the decrypting one), as it will replace the earlier definitions - this is not what you're intending.

You've then linked all buttons to this function.

So, the first thing you need to change, is to give each function its own name:

```
def encrypt()
    ...
def decrypt()
    ...
```

Then, you need to change how you've linked the buttons to the function.

You have two options:

1) Have a generic press function, that uses an IF statement on the button name, to determine the action:

```
def press(btn):
    if btn == "Encrypt":
        encrypt()
    elif btn == "Decrypt":
        decrypt()
    elif btn == "Close":
        app.stop()

app.addButtons(["Encrypt", "Decrypt", "Close"], press)
```

2) Directly link each button to the correct function.

```
app.addButtons(["Encrypt", "Decrypt", "Close"], [encrypt, decrypt, app.stop])
```

Later on, you'll come across the same issues with your `Submit` & `Back` buttons, and will need to use the same tactics...